# JProfiler Remote Application Integration in web sphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, jprofiler

We are using Web Sphere 8.5 and JProfiler 8.1. I want to hook the JVM runnning in Web Sphere 8.5. I have completed the remote appl;ication integration and after that we have to add into the Startup command of my remote application right after Java command.

```
-Xshareclasses:none -agentpath:/opt/jprofiler/bin/aix-ppc64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849
```

`"StartServer.sh"` file is the start command of Web Sphere.

Could you please confirm that we have add the above command after below line of `"StartServer.sh"` or "setupCmdLine.sh"(if file is called by StartServer.sh) ?

`JAVA_EXE = "{JAVA_HOME}/bin/java"` -- Do we have to add in this line of `StartServer.sh or setupCmdLine.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM parameters for the server go into server.xml, not into the start script. The start script just starts an admin server that terminates when the operation is complete.

I would recommend to use the Websphere integration wizard under

Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration

Comment: But after finishing remote application we are getting one message like below.

**Integration type: [Generic application]
Selected JVM: IBM 1.6.0 (jit compiler)
Startup mode: Wait for a connection from the JProfiler GUI**

(1) Please insert

**-Xshareclasses:none -agentpath:/opt/jprofiler/bin/aix-ppc64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849**

into the start command of your remote application right after the java command.

You mean start command is nothing but **server.xml** of the server??

Comment: yes, in that case, the admin server starts another JVM and the VM parameters are in that file. If you use the Websphere integration wizard instead of the generic integration wizard, it will make the modifications for you

Comment: Thanks Ingo Kegel for the clarification. 
One more doubt i have. After configuring Specified JVM in Web Sphere **Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration** , when i will open the configured Web Sphere Session and Click on start, whether Jprofiler will start the specified JVM or i have go to the server and start the JVM manually ? 

As while integrating server we are giving the **StartServer.sh** file path.

Comment: The JVM that you select in the integration wizard is just to inform JProfiler which JVM will be used, so it can insert the correct VM parameter. THe profiling agent will not start any JVM by itself.